# give every occurrence of a unique field in mongodb database a new unique field

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a database that has 1.3 million documents with the following schema:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592b04226e46690549744e71"),
    "game" : "xyz",
    "game_id" : "161936",
    "username" : "jomonsugi",
    "rating" : 10,
    "comment" : "Good game. "
}
```

Throughout the database, there are multiple occurrences of the same username. I want to add a new field that gives every user their own unique id. Example: "user_id" : "12345". So in the example above every document in the db with "username" : "jomonsugi" would have a field/value added to it with the same unique user_id for every occurrence.

I have something that works, but it takes hours (literally) and as the db grows it will take days. I use distinct to get a list of all users from the db, then I give all users a unique id number in a dictionary {"username" : "user_id"} then I use update:

```
client = MongoClient()
    db = client.bgg
    for k,v in id_dic.items():
        print(k,v)
        db.game_comments.update({ 'username': k } ,{ '$set' : { 'user_id': v } }, multi = True )
```

This works just fine, and I have seen post on how slow the update method is, however is there a way to accomplish this task any faster? Maybe a mongo function I am missing?

Comment: I hope I receive an answer someday that allows me to check for duplicates in a mongodb database based on unique fields before inserting a new document (or a mongo update), however, for the time being, I found some duct tape. Inserting documents takes relatively no time at all, so I am just inserting new documents without checking for duplicates and then since the ObjectId has a timestamp in it, I delete all duplicates after all insertions are finished, keeping only the newest. Seems like a hack to me, but it saves a month (literally) of compute time in my case.